# Как правильно: строчнАя буква или стрОчная буква?

Tags: ударение

В словаре Резниченко даны два варианта: строчнОй и стрОчный (= не прописной). Не могу найти информацию об истории этих вариантов,  также непонятно, какой и почему следует употреблять в современной речи.

Информация для размышления (из форумов):

Ребенок пошел в первый класс, и с тех пор словосочетание "строчнАя буква" просто режет слух, но так говорит учитель.

Мне тоже режет слух строчнАя, вы не одиноки. Никогда раньше не слыхал ни от кого такое произношения, я бы сразу заметил расхождение с моим мнением и стал бы разбираться.

Большое спасибо за информацию. Так получается, что  строчнАя буква – это начальный вариант, а стрОчная – более поздний. Я, признаться,  считала слово "строчнОй" нововведением.  Тогда можно предположить, что второй вариант может вытеснить первый. (Хотя, к примеру, на радио есть передача "Говорим по-русски", и там они произносят "строчнАя буква").

Меня вариант  "стрОчный" больше устраивает вот по каким причинам. Кроме буквы, существует еще строчнОй шов. Он уж точно строчнОй, от  глагола «строчить», буква Ч при этом сохраняется. А вот в «строчнОй букве» исходное существительное изменяется значительно: кроме безударной редукции гласного, еще и чередование К/Ч. В итоге «строка» становится просто неузнаваемой. Поэтому прилагательное «стрОчный» и звучит лучше, и отличает букву от шва.

Язык развивается от менее совершенных форм к более совершенным, следовательно, у новой формы есть преимущество. А какое? Оно связано с  фонетической формой или лучше передает содержание слова? Почему строчнАя буква так многим режет слух? Кроме того, хотелось бы в более общей форме представить, как смысловые оттенки слова зависят от ударения. Почему мы говорим языковОй и языкОвый, вАловый и валовОй, запаснОй и запАсный. Что означает ударение на корне, суффиксе и окончании в подобных словах?

Answer (score 3):

От слова СТРОКА-строчнАя, от слова СТРОЧКА-стрОчная. Так как раньше использовалось только слово СТРОКА, а Ожегов не признаёт никаких уменьшительных слов в науке, он даёт только вариант строчнОй,строчнАя. Но язык изменяется, сейчас и СТРОЧКА - общелитературное слово, употребляется во всех стилях (Пушкин бы с этим поспорил),поэтому по отношению в букве говорят и так и так, и это допустимо.Но взгляды на это у учёных расходятся.

Справочник Былинского и Никольского (1952) - строчнОй .

Словарь Аванесова и Ожегова (1959) - строчнОй, - Ая, -Ое.

Словарь Зализняка(1977) - строчнОй и доп. стрОчный

Орфоэпический словарь Аванесова (1989) - строчнОй, -Ая, -Ое и доп. стрОчный, -ая, -ое.

Русский орфографический словарь(2000) - строчнОй (строчнОе шитьё, строчнЫе буквы, строчнОе пение) 
только стрОчный  -стрОчная  развёртка телеизображения.

БТС под ред. Кузнецова - строчнОй и стрОчный (о буквах); 
- только строчнОй (о шитье); 
- только стрОчный (развёртка изображения) 
Учителя-последователи Ожегова говорят строчнАя, но остальными это воспринимается уже как профессионализм,произношение стрОчная стало преобладающим. Ну это вроде как старомосковское ДОЩ, которое мы произносим как ДОЖДЬ и считаем правильным, а кто-то поправляет и говорит, что это  неправильно.

Comment: >От слова СТРОКА-строчнАя, от слова СТРОЧКА-стрОчная.  
  
Это неверное объяснение. От "строчка" - строчечный. Подробнее - в моем ответе.

Comment: Я говорю о том, как появилось слово стрОчная в современном языке. Раньше строка букв была только строкой, а строчка от строчить(швейная), потом появилось уменьшительное строчка-маленькая строка, но учёные не признавали это за норму в науке строчка=строка, только как уменьшительное, потом появилось переносное значение " Ровный ряд, цепочка чего-л." ( С. звериных следов. Огненные строчки трассирующих пуль). К буквам это тоже приложимо, слово вошло в норму в этом значении тоже.Об этом говорил проф.Прозоров в одной из передач о русском языке.

Comment: Там спрашивалось, как правильно: строка или строчка стихов.Он ответил: если речь о строгом термине, книжном слове, то строка, если просто в разговоре, лучше строчка,это звучит неофициально. Отсюда строчнАя буква - официальное название, термин, стрОчная- неофициальное.Вот его объяснение.

Comment: >Я говорю о том, как появилось слово стрОчная в современном языке  
  
Так и я о том же. От "строчка" (диминутив) было бы "строчечный".

Впрочем, от другой "строчки" (действие по глаголу строчить) - скорее всего - тоже. Хотя такие существительные сами по себе вообще крайне "неохотно" порождают прилагательные. 
Так что объяснение "От слова СТРОКА-строчнАя, от слова СТРОЧКА-стрОчная" принять за истину никак не могу, хотя слышать приходилось частенько.  

Кстати, близкородственность "строка" и "строчить" очевилна и без привлечения "строчки".

Comment: Вы о словарях, о научном словообразовании, а я о том, как народное словообразование стало нормой. Кто-то признаёт за допустимый вариант, а кто-то за равноправный. Один из примеров влияния разговорной речи на язык.

Answer (score 3):

Я за строчной, строчнАя.

Вообще исторически это объяснялось разными значениями.
Строчный (стрОчные объявления, стрОчная развертка)  - состоящий из строк или строчек, даваемый по строкам, связанный ***со строками***. *В словарях XIX - начала XX века это значение не представлено по причине отсутствия самого понятия*.

СтрочнОй (строчной шов, строчнАя буква) - строчечный, размером со строку, сделанный с помощью строки, связанный ***со строкой***. Сюда же, естественно, "строчной шов" - простроченный, сделанный строчкой.
Увы, в современных реалиях это различие совершенно смазано, это приводит к появлению других объяснений и правил, подчас - совершенно фантастических. А в конечном счете - к изрядной путанице. Можно полагать, что в конечном счете исторический вариант с ударением на флексию окончательно устареет. Но пока этого не произошло.

Кстати, подобные обсуждения можно легко найти едва ли не на любом профильном форуме.
Вот одно (из нескольких) на "Грамоте".
http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1089&p=35985

Answer (score 2):

В Орфоэпическом словаре Аванесова даны оба варианта:  строчнОй и доп. стрОчный (не прописной).

В словаре Русское словесное ударение (автор Зарва): строчнОй (но без помет, имеется в виду шов или буквы, мне кажется, что буквы).

Но, если я не ошибаюсь, словарь Аванесова считается авторитетным. Мне "строчнАя" тоже слух режет.

Посмотрела еще словари Ушакова и Ожегова... Там строчнОй... Вопросов больше, чем ответов.